# how to make a Spring cloud stream Processor Function that takes kstream (Kafka stream) to work timely basis?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

So I have scenario where my **cloud stream Processor function** reads message from one **Kafka** topic-1 and produces the message to another Kafka topic-2. But this process has to run on timely basis like the function should wait for 5 minutes and after that it should start (consume n Produce) for 1 minute, then after 1 minute again will wait for another 5 minute. Could anyone please help me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Stream functions are event-driven and therefore you cannot control the time of the consumption. It will be consumed as soon as it is available to the binder. If this is a hard requirement, I suggest writing a regular bean with `Scheduled` annotation from Spring and use Spring for Apache Kafka to consume from the first topic and then immediately produce to the second topic. You can use `KafkaListener` and `KafkaTemplate` from Sping Kafka (or `StreamBridge` from Spring Cloud Stream for sending to Kafka). Once the records are in the second topic, then you can use still use Kafka Streams binder to do further stream processing.

Comment: The question says different topics, nothing about different clusters

Comment: @sobychacko - Thank you for your response. Here we have a single cluster. it involves two different topics. i have to consume from one topic and produce it to another. But this whole process i need to control in timely manner.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question properly. I updated the answer above.